# Why bigquery download automatically my queries when I try to export it without choosing the location?

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, export, export-csv

I'm working with GCP Bigquery and Its very common for me export some queries as CSV in my local computer. The thing is that a few weeks ago the exportation name of the tables change from a format like "results-YYYYMMDD-TIME" to "bquxjob_etc etc etc". Besides, since yesterday when I export it download automatically in my download folder, without asking where I want to save it.
On the other hand, when some value is null, came the word "null" as a result. Could it be related?

I have a macbook air, I'm using Google Chrome and yes, I have the option of automatically download off.

Any idea of What is going on or how can I solve it?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

There could have been changes done internally to affect the things you have mentioned.

1. I can confirm that the filename of the CSV is the "bquxjob_etc etc etc".csv
2. Downloaded CSV file is automatically be downloaded to your browsers default download location. This was added to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#downloading_query_results_to_a_local_file).
3. If you want naming convention "results-YYYYMMDD-TIME" when downloading, you can opt to [downloading the data to Google Sheets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#saving-query-results-to-sheets).
4. The data downloaded to Google Sheets does not have the word "null".

   - Actual Query result:

     - [image]
   - Exported Query results to sheets:

     - [image]

As a workaround if you want to retain the "results-yyyy-mmdd-time" naming convention and no "null" values. I suggest to export query results to Google Sheets and download the data as CSV.

You can also send a feedback to the BigQuery team about the changes made.

**To send a feedback with regards to the new UI:**

1. Open any [BigQuery documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMn9r.png)
2. Click "Send feedback"
3. Choose "BigQuery Product feedback"

> [image]

4. Fill up the form with your feed back

Comment: Thank`s Ricco!
The thing is still see null when I paste it in excel file. I will do What you mentioned and I will send feedback to Google! :)
Thanks!!

Comment: @MATIASVALENZUELA Did you copy the data from the exported CSV or data from Google sheets?

Comment: directly from the exported CSV.

Comment: @MATIASVALENZUELA I see. You can export it to Google Sheets then save it as CSV so the "null" values won't appear if that is not a hassle for you =)